# Get DocSet name from a file in a document library

Tags: document-set

I am processing all the files in a document library. I need to get the file as well as its metadata.  That's relatively easy.  But for each file I would also like to get the name of the Document Set it is in if any.  I see plenty of advice on getting all the files in a Document Set but nothing the other way around.  Can anyone help?

Comment: What flavor of code / data access are you using?  C#/server-side, CSOM, JSOM, Javascript/REST?

Comment: Oh, sorry I should have said CSOM.